# Java ArrayList<JTextField> as parameter on Java method

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

This is code for clearing my text fields on my form in method form.

```
public void clearFlds(String toBeReplace){
    ArrayList<JTextField> fldr = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(txtfname,txtmname,txtlname,txtaddress));
    for (JTextField jflds: fldr){
        jflds.setText(toBeReplace);
    }
}


private void btnClearActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    clearFlds("");
}
```

As you can see the

```
Arrays.asList(txtfname,txtmname,txtlname,txtaddress)
```

is static on my method, Can someone help me how to make a Arrays.asList as parameter so that I will just pass all the JTextField name on parameters as many JTextField name as I want to pass.

Somehow this is the output on my mind, instead of putting the JTextField name on the method I just want it to be pass as parameter.

NOTE: this is just a pseudo code on my mind.

```
private void btnClearActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    clearFlds(ArrayList.asList(txtfname,txtmname,txtlname,txtaddress), "");
}
```

I would greatly appreciate you for helping me build my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `List<JTextField>` as parameter in clearFlds().

Your code should look like the one below.

```
public void clearFlds(List<JTextField> textFields, String toBeReplace){
    for (JTextField jflds: textFields){
        jflds.setText(toBeReplace);
    }
}


private void btnClearActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    clearFlds(Arrays.asList(txtfname,txtmname,txtlname,txtaddress),"");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. this helps me alot, much appreciated. simple and clean code.